# Data Algebra vs SQL based databases Query Performance

Tags: oracle, algebraixlib

Since Data Algebra is all mathematics. Is there a way to find out performance difference between Data Algebra and SQL based databases like Oracle in a mathematical way. By mathematical way I mean Big O notation or some other way that prove performance cost mathematically for a table scan on insertion.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The performance of a given query depends on the implementation of the query engine. The performance gains that data algebra makes possible come from the possibility to use mathematical operations and transformations with proven correctness. This makes a number of approaches practical that wouldn't be without data algebra -- but their performance still depends on their specific implementation, not on the underlying mathematics.

Comment: Somebody have already answer similiar question I asked. Your statement contradict with this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32972084/how-to-find-the-time-complexity-of-the-algebra-operation-in-algebraixlib?noredirect=1#comment54413349_32972084). Only problem is that link answer that its very generic and does not provide enough information to understand the whole question.

Comment: I don't think that there is a contradiction. From the answer you linked to:

> It is important to note that the above section describes the time 
> complexity that is _specific to the algorithms implemented in 
> algebraixlib_."

That's exactly what I am saying here: Any performance considerations are specific to a given implementation of the query engine (`algebraixlib` in the case of the answer you linked to).